# geting Error on pdffiller : spawn pdftk ENOENT

Tags: node.js, pdftk

I use `pdffiller` on my project

> npm install pdffiller

and this is my code

```js
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          pdfFiller.fillFormWithFlatten(sourcePDF,distPath,formValues,false,function (err) {
              if (err) {
                return reject(err);
              }
              return resolve({
                url: distPath
              });
            }
          );
        });
```

and my pdf is editable and has checkboxes, input boxes and etc.

> that pdf saved on `sourcePDF` directory

> pdf filled with `formValues` object

every time I try to fill the pdf got this error

```error
Error: spawn pdftk ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn pdftk',
  path: 'pdftk',
  spawnargs: [
    'public/uploads/test/0.pdf',
    'fill_form',
    'temp_data1601654837427pd8bn.fdf',
    'output',
    'public/uploads/providers/4939/test/9e6020c5-2369-45fd-b75b-250d7edb3ec5-populate.pdf'
  ],
  cmd: 'pdftk public/uploads/test/0.pdf fill_form temp_data1601654837427pd8bn.fdf output public/uploads/providers/4939/test/9e6020c5-2369-45fd-b75b-250d7edb3ec5-populate.pdf'
}
```

Comment: You'll need to install the pdftk system package to use pdffiller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [AKX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51685/akx)

it can be installed on snap

> sudo snap install pdftk

and my problem is fixed

Comment: how can i make this work in the windows subsystem linux?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you need to install snap on wsl2

Comment: How can we use this in Windows??

Comment: you need to install windows version. you can find it in here 
https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/

Answer (score 0):

Per AKX, you will need to install https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/